# How can we get 3D volume of Dicom CT images - Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pydicom, numpy-ndarray

Learning processing DICOM images and Python, please bear with me for any silly questions.

I am working on converting CT DICOM image slices to Volume which could be further used to display in 3D and also manipulate for further equations. As I understand, pixel values are stored in pixel_array header, I am unable to figure out, how to visualize the volume of these individual slices, one suggestion I saw is to initialize blank matrix where vol = matrix of size (pixelwidth, pixelheight, slices) using numpy zeros, though I understand pixelwidth and pixelheight are columns and rows I can get from DICOM header, not sure what slices are. Also, I found following code which gives similar result in multiple areas on web, however unable to point to where they used volume in following, I ultimately need to understand how I could get these individual images data in 3D volume matrix, thank you:
https://www.raddq.com/dicom-processing-segmentation-visualization-in-python/

```py
def load_scan(path):
    slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.InstanceNumber))
    try:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].ImagePositionPatient[2] - slices[1].ImagePositionPatient[2])
    except:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].SliceLocation - slices[1].SliceLocation)
    for s in slices:
        s.SliceThickness = slice_thickness
    return slices

def get_pixels_hu(scans):
    image = np.stack([s.pixel_array for s in scans])
    # Convert to int16 (from sometimes int16), 
    # should be possible as values should always be low enough (<32k)
    image = image.astype(np.int16)
    # Set outside-of-scan pixels to 1
    # The intercept is usually -1024, so air is approximately 0
    image[image == -2000] = 0
    # Convert to Hounsfield units (HU)
    intercept = scans[0].RescaleIntercept
    slope = scans[0].RescaleSlope
    if slope != 1:
        image = slope * image.astype(np.float64)
    image = image.astype(np.int16)
    image += np.int16(intercept)
    return np.array(image, dtype=np.int16)
    
id = 0
patient = load_scan(data_path)
imgs = get_pixels_hu(patient)
```

Comment: When posting python code, it would be helpful to retain the indentation so the code blocks/logic are clear.

Comment: with CT you usually get one slice per DICOM file.